# Configurar carga de sitio web

Tags: javascript, html

> La consulta que tengo es algo genérica, no creo que haga falta nisiquiera poner un código para poder resolverla, pero como entiendo que no funciona asi, pongo un script que tengo para el inicio de un sitio web. Tengo un section principal con fondo blanco, donde se van a escribir un texto letra por letra. El tema es que, al abrir el sitio, empieza a cargar los elementos y a escribir (renderizar la parte del landing, digamos) al mismo tiempo, y al hacer las dos cosas en simultaneo, el texto se traba al escribirse. Es como si se cargara "lageado", con letras que tardan en cargarse, o de repente se imprimen 4 letras juntas.

**Lo que busco:** Quisiera poder mostrar alguna imagen (tipo un gif loader) mientras se cargan todos los recursos, y una vez que pase esto, que se empiece a escribir el texto abajo mencionado. Podrian ayudarme con eso? Muchas gracias.

```js
 
        function maquinaDeEscribir(e){
            const textoArray = e.innerHTML.split('');
            e.innerHTML = '';
            textoArray.forEach((letra,i) => {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    e.innerHTML += letra;
                },200*i)
            });
        }
        function maquinaDeEscribirTexto(e){
            const textoArray = e.innerHTML.split('');
            e.innerHTML = '';
            textoArray.forEach((letra,i) => {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    e.innerHTML += letra;
                },105*i)
            });
        }
        const texto = document.querySelector('#texto');
        const titulo= document.querySelector('#titulo');
        const img = document.querySelector('#arrow-bottom');
        
        const aw = document.querySelector('#awwwards');

        maquinaDeEscribir(titulo);
        setTimeout(function(){
            texto.style.display = 'block'
            maquinaDeEscribirTexto(texto);
        },2000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            aw.style.display = 'block';

        },8000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            img.style.display = 'block'

        },8500);


        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 20) {
    img.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    img.style.display = 'block'
  }
});
```

```html
 <div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle maquinadeescribir">
        <h1 id="titulo" >Bienvenidos</h1>
        <h2 id="texto" style="display:none" >Este es un texto de prueba</h2>

        
        <div id="contenedor-arrow" style="position: fixed; bottom: 10px; vertical-align: center; width: 100%;">
           <a href="#about" data-uk-scroll="">
               <img id="arrow-bottom" class="uk-animation-scale-up" src="/images/arrow.gif" width="60px" alt="agustin.wtf" style="display:none;  margin: 0 auto" >
           </a> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Puedes usar el evento DOMContentLoaded,  y dentro de este, ya tu sitio y su contenido habra cargado,  asi que quitarias el giff,  y para el caso de donde colocarias el giff lo que puedes hacer es que se cargue el script primero antes que todos tus recursos,  (y muy importante que lo dejes fuera de DOMContentLoaded,  por que fuera de DOMContentLoaded La pagina aun no habra cargado,  y cuande se cargue en DOMContentLoaded, simplemente quitas el giff

Comment: creo que no te entendi bien. Por un lado, no es 100% necesario lo del gif, solo que me imaginaba que si hay que esperar a que la pagina cargue, era bueno mostrar un loader. Por otro lado, no entiendo como colocar el sitio dentro del evento. El sitio es un index.html y hay 12 archivos .js correspondientes a librerias

Comment: No el sitio,  el script,  pero no todo el script.